# Provide both REST and SOAP endpoints for webservices

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, servicestack

I was a great fun of [Service Stack](https://servicestack.net/) until it has gone commercial and they officially stopped the [support of older versions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes-v3). My main problem is that I want to be able to write a service and support both REST and SOAP xml. The reason being that most of my business clients work with WSDL and "Add service reference" but I have some other clients that would prefer to work with REST APIs as they follow the latest tech stacks.

Personally I have used the [Agatha rrsl](http://davybrion.github.io/Agatha/) from the mighty Davy Brion but it is not actively maintained any more. I guess one could go the extra mile to maintain it on its own but I'd rather find another working framework.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

if you are interesting about SOAP, the free BSD version of ServiceStack 3.9.71, is excellent for you.

Do you think that  you  will need  official  support for  SOAP  updates ?

Is it mature enough ? I think yes , at least about your issue.

Nevertheless, in open source communities, there are  always contributors.
There is not  official support. Never, this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well of course Web API (http://www.asp.net/web-api) is one option. I also like Nancy (http://nancyfx.org/) a lot because it allows easily to change part of framework (like di container).

Comment: I do not consider Web API as an option as it doesn't support SOAP operations and of course since I used Servicestack in the first place it means that I have already turned Web Api down.

Comment: Oh thats a good point that running both SOAP and REST is not supported. This site contains a nice list of services:
http://www.agile-code.com/blog/what-technology-for-building-web-services-in-microsoft-net/